# Weird Laravel Encryption EncryptString error

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I've been running into a really weird error with the Laravel EncryptString function, curious if anyone has any idea whats wrong.

Basically, I'm encrypting emails in PHP using Laravel, and then later decrypting it with both Laravel and Python. The Laravel code seems to work fine, and the Python code works fine for 99% of my test cases, BUT it glitches out whenever I use my own domain name in the email I'm encrypting.

My Code:

```
public function encryptEmail(Request $request) {
    if (!Auth::check() && !Auth::viaRemember()) {
            return redirect()->to('/login');
    }
    $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'bail|required|email',
    ]);
    $emailToEncrypt = $request->request->get('email');
    $encryptedEmail = Crypt::encryptString($emailToEncrypt);
    $email = Emails::where('accountId', Auth::id())->first();
    $email->val = $encryptedEmail;
    $email->save();
```

The Problem:
Everything works fine when I'm encrypting emails NOT from my own domain the webserver is running on.

Example:

```
 string in form           decrypt PHP          decrypt Python
'test@gmail.com' =>     'test@gmail.com',    'test@gmail.com'
'myEmail@icloud.com' => 'myEmail@icloud.com' 'myEmail@icloud.com'
'other@hotmail.com' =>  'other@hotmail.com'  'other@hotmail.com'
'me@mydomain.com' =>    'me@mydomain.com'    'me@my'
```

As you can see, it seems like once it gets to my domain, it seems like the string encryption gets cut off, I've checked that the entire string is passed into EncryptString so really not sure what would make the Python code glitch out on emails with our domain.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:

Python Code where enc is the encrypted Laravel data

```
def decrypt(enc):
    key = base64.b64decode("MyKey=")
    dataDict = json.loads(base64.b64decode(enc))

    decrypter = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, base64.b64decode(dataDict['iv']))
    data = decrypter.decrypt(base64.b64decode(dataDict['value']))

    try:
        print(data.decode())
        return data.decode()
    except Exception as e:
        return None
```

Comment: The actual python code that is generating the problems would be nice to add.

Comment: @YouriKoeman just added it.